# stop maven from checking for updates

Tags: eclipse, maven

How can I stop maven from checking for updates each time I start debugging a project from Eclipse? I hope this makes sense as I'm not too familiar with the java development environment.

It's just that everytime I start debugging, it will go checking for snapshot updates for dependent libraries. And this gets annoying on a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `-o` flag if you're using the command line. From `mvn -h`:

> -o,--offline                  Work offline

---

If you're using some sort of Maven integration like [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/), the launch configurations usually have a 'Offline' check box.

---

### Alternative: don't use SNAPSHOTs

Some might say that you're better of declaring release versions for all your plugins and dependencies, since that makes your build repeatable, i.e. instead of using

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

use

```
<version>1.1</version>
```